# Gmail IMAP telling me to "please log in using your web browser"

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, authentication, imap, multi-factor-auth

I've started using an organizational Gmail account (i.e. myself@myorg.org where myorg has a Google Applications subscription or whatever it is they call it).

Now, I can log in via the web and read my email and that's all fine. However, if I try to log in with IMAP (using the settings Google's support indicates), my login fails, and I get a message saying:

> Alert from account myself@myorg.org@gmail.com:
>   Please log in via your web browser:
>   http://support.google.com/mail/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=78754
>  (Failure)

I went there, and followed the instructions - up to "App Passwords". When I try generating an "App Password", I get a page saying:

> The setting you are looking for is not available for your account.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it may seem counter-intuitive, Google believes your IMAP client is a "less secure application" relative to your web browser. You must therefore

> Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.

- Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- (log in if necessary to get there)
- Flip the switch named "Allow less secure apps" to the ON state.

You should now be able to login via IMAP.